# fetch.max.message.bytes and max.message.bytes Kafka configurations

Tags: apache-kafka, configuration

I'm still new to Kafka, and I'm unsure why there is a consumer and producer parameter for max message size. Having two parameters just seems like it introduces errors that developers might overlook (i.e setting the `fetch.max.message.bytes` lower than the `max.message.bytes`). There must be a use-case or design-pattern that I'm missing, that motivated the Kafka team to keep both of these configuration values.

Comment: Which kafka version are you using?

Comment: Also, I can't find `fetch.max.message.bytes` in the [ConsumerConfig](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html) nor `max.message.bytes` in the [ProducerConfig](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html). To be able to provide an answer, you need to be more precise.

Comment: Hmm ya - looks like the documentation I was reading was referring to a much older Kafka version (should have thought to check the Consumer and Producer config docs to check). This came up when I was reading The Definitive Guide to Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So fetch.max.message.bytes doesn't exist (at least in the latest Kafka versions, so what are you using?), I guess you are referring to fetch.max.bytes instead.
Anyway, fetch.max.bytes and max.message.bytes are on broker (not producer/consumer).
The max.message.bytes define the maximum size of each batch of messages that a consumer can get (you know messages are batched so grouped together).
The fetch.max.bytes defines a maximum limits on how many batches a consumer can get in one shot from the broker; it's not an hard limit because if there are more available batches, the broker returns part of them until the maximum to avoid having the consumer stuck.